# Windows form ArgumentException was unhandled

Tags: c#

I have a image slideshow project for which the user is expected to choose an images folder which the form takes in a PictureBox and slideshows, the project runs and allows me to select an images folder after which it then throws an ArgumentException meant to be thrown if the directory does not exist. Below is the code for the method within which the exception is thrown:

```
public static string[] GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern)
    {
        string[] patterns = searchPattern.Split(';');
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        foreach (string filter in patterns)
        {
            // Iterate through the directory tree and ignore the 
            // DirectoryNotFoundException or UnauthorizedAccessException 
            // exceptions.                 

            // Data structure to hold names of subfolders to be
            // examined for files.
            Stack<string> dirs = new Stack<string>(20);

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            dirs.Push(path);

            while (dirs.Count > 0)
            {
                string currentDir = dirs.Pop();
                string[] subDirs;
                try
                {
                    subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
                }
                // An UnauthorizedAccessException exception will be thrown 
                // if we do not have discovery permission on a folder or 
                // file. It may or may not be acceptable to ignore the 
                // exception and continue enumerating the remaining files 
                // and folders. It is also possible (but unlikely) that a 
                // DirectoryNotFound exception will be raised. This will 
                // happen if currentDir has been deleted by another 
                // application or thread after our call to Directory.Exists. 
                // The choice of which exceptions to catch depends entirely 
                // on the specific task you are intending to perform and 
                // also on how much you know with certainty about the 
                // systems on which this code will run.
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(currentDir, filter));
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Push the subdirectories onto the stack for traversal.
                // This could also be done before handing the files.
                foreach (string str in subDirs)
                {
                    dirs.Push(str);
                }
            }
        }

        return files.ToArray();
    }
```

Assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Ooh, sorry, the question is: Why am I getting the ArgumentException when the program allows me to choose the folder to use for the slideshow?

Comment: Are you getting the exception on your `throw new ArgumentException();` line or is something else throwing it?

Comment: Read the remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx#remarksToggle)

Comment: yeah, its on that line